# Maven exec:exec - Need additional classpath elements for plugin

Tags: java, maven

I'm using the maven exec plugin to run my project.  My project has a Start class that uses embedded Jetty to run the app.  The dependency in the normal part of the POM for jetty is marked as "provided" because I don't want it in the final WAR.

How do I tell the exec plugin to add the 2 jars below to the classpath when running `mvn exec:exec`?  The `executableDepedency` elements do not add it to the classpath.  Currently, the classpath is all of the dependency jars that are not marked `test` or `provided`.

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executableDependency>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                </executableDependency>
                <executableDependency>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-management</artifactId>
                    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                </executableDependency>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath />                       
                    <argument>net.mikeski.Start</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: It's funny to me that the answer to this (which is correct) is at -2 but the thing just got 1K views...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out there are 2 options that you can use with Maven when using exec:java (which is what I wanted).  You can specify true/false for each:

- use the project dependencies in the classpath
- use the plugin dependencies in the classpath

So, I added my `provided` project dependencies as plugin dependencies and set both of the properties to true and it works.

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-management</artifactId>
                        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <mainClass>com.whatever.Main</mainClass>
              </configuration>
        ...
```